# How can I close a modal only after the routed page loads in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a website for my first Next JS project. In my navbar when viewed on mobile, I am hiding the links and displaying a hamburger button which, on click, opens a full-screen modal which has all the links displayed. I am handling the modal with state, showing it with a ternary only when menuIsOpen is true. This is from my navbar component:

```
    export default function Navbar() {
    const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);

    function closeMenuModal() {
      if (menuIsOpen) setMenuIsOpen(false);
      else setMenuIsOpen(true);
    }
    
    return (      
          ...
          {menuIsOpen ? (
            <MenuModal          
              closeMenuModal={closeMenuModal}
            />
          ) : null}
      )
    }
```

There is also other code of course that opens the modal. On MenuModal.jsx, I have link components like this:

```
export default function MenuModal({ closeMenuModal }) {
  return (
        <Link onClick={closeMenuModal} href="/about">
          ABOUT
        </Link>
  );
}
```

The behavior I want is to click one of the links, like ABOUT, and for the modal to close to reveal the page the user clicked. This is working, however what happens is the modal closes and the user sees the current page before the new page loads.

What is the best way to make it so the modal closes only once the new page loads, revealing the new page and not flashing the previous? My first impulse was to just pass down the isMenuOpen state and setter as props, but I don't know how to accomplish this since I am using a Link component and reaching the page via Next's routing. I know I can send it as an object query in the Link and use useRouter, but I don't want it to be in the URL, and this would not allow me to also pass the state setter function, which I need to close the modal.

Is there a way to do this, or am I fundamentally approaching this wrong?

Comment: I am using Next JS and their build in <Link> component, which uses 
"href" as opposed to React Router which uses "to".

Comment: Right you are, my bad